# SQLGeography in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Строю полигоны в c# и заполняю ими соответствующую табличку в sqlserver(где уже есть информация и айдишники полигонов), примерно вот так:

```
updateCommandRelations.CommandText = "UPDATE [Polygons] SET [Polygon] = geography::STGeomFromText('" + polygonString + "', 4326) WHERE IdPolygons = " + idPolygons; 
updateCommandRelations.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Всё вроде без ошибок проходит, но тут я решил проверить, как же они строятся, используя возможности SSMS, и вижу это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Почему же полигон охватывает весь земной шар? Такс, давайте разбираться, приближаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, почти то, что я и хотел, только наоборот, выделенная область должна быть внутри, а не снаружи) Пришлось перерыть интернет, и  оказалось, что действительно, есть разница как выстраивать точки в полигоне: по часовой стрелке(полигон - область вне):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]или против часовой(полигон - область внутри):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но заметил это, когда отстроил около 500 тысяч полигонов(прошу заметить примерно 48 часов работы приложения), когда встал вопрос: "входит ли точка в полигон?" (проверял только в самом программе замкнутость полигонов и порядок выстраивания точек, но не мог и догадываться, что направление имеет значение).

Использовал функцию STContains и ,естественно, полигонов в ответе было больше, чем мне нужно.

```
selectCommand.CommandText = "DECLARE @g geography; 
SET @g=geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(" + lng.Replace(",", ".") + " " + lat.Replace(",", ".") + ")', 4326); 
SELECT Info FROM [Polygons] WHERE ([Polygon].MakeValid()).STContains(@g) = 1;";
```

Так подошли к сути вопроса, как с этим бороться, не перестраивая полигоны(использовать отрицание нельзя, так как половина полигонов построилось по часовой стрелке, половина против)?(есть идея костыля типа проверки какой-нибудь крайней точки, и если входит, то инверсия ответа)

А если это, увы, невозможно после построения, то как же отследить при построении, что полигон строится именно против часовой стрелки?

Comment: Если известно, что все полигоны в Вашей задаче должны быть разумных размеров, то можно проверять площадь полигона (`STarea()`), и если она больше половины площади земного шара, то считать, что полигон был задан неправильно и использовать `ReorientObject()`.

Comment: некоторые полигоны могут быть размером с континент, решение возможное, но не общее всё же.

Comment: Земные континенты все равно по площади существенно меньше половины земного шара. :)

Comment: @Yaant ну мало ли будет океан какой-нибудь полигоном)) подумываю вот это использовать: EnvelopeAngle() > 90 или EnvelopeAngle() = 180, пока не понял, как точно работает эта функция, а потом ReorientObject().

Comment: Ну и если не вводить подобного рода ограничений, то задача неразрешима в принципе: простейший пример: все вершины полигона располагаются на экваторе, при этом неизвестно, вводились ли они в правильном порядке, или в обратном. Как в этом случае определить, какое полушарие должно быть выбрано, южное или северное? Никак.

Comment: @Yaant полигон всегда должен быть замкнут. если обвести точками южное полушарие, то логично его выбрать, а не то, что вокруг(соответственно северное). Как я понял, подобные различия(по часовой и против часовой) были сделаны для инверсии, для задач, когда нужно выбрать всё, кроме выделенного полигона, вот это более логично. а ваш пример либо для чего-то другого(и я не очень понял его), либо ошибочный.

Comment: Проблема в том, что "обвести точками южное полушарие" - это то же самое, что "обвести точками северное полушарие", точки будут ровно те же самые. Как Вы, зная только точки, поймете, какое из двух полушарий было обведено?

Comment: @Yaant да, ошибся, в данном случае действительно будет неразбериха.

Comment: @Yaant и как определить направление тогда? условно вторая точка должна быть "выше" или "на том же уровне, но правее"?

Comment: В том-то и беда, что без дополнительной информации - никак. Пример с экватором взят просто для наглядности, на самом деле он применим всегда: вот точки окружают какую-то небольшую область, но как понять, это выделен остров в океане, или, наоборот, океан, окружающий остров? На плоскости ещё можно было бы использовать тот факт, что внутренняя часть полигона ограничена, а внешняя - нет, но на сфере это уже не работает.